# How to play live microphone sound over speakers?

Tags: 11.10, sound, microphone, playback, speakers

Is there a way I could enable live playback from microphone? It could use at karaoke or as a guitar amplifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There are](http://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu%20karaoke) [multiple ways](http://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu%20guitar%20amp).

[Performous](http://performous.org/) and [UltraStar Deluxe](http://www.multimediaboom.com/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-into-a-karaoke-machine/) look perfect for karaoke, and [Guitarix](http://guitarix.sourceforge.net/) should do as amp.

Comment: UltraStar Deluxe seems to not have a ppa for oneiric, and song list for Performous is very limited. I was looking for something more wide in terms of songs. My guitar doesn't have jack (it isn't an electric one). Anyway, I guess playing live sound requires more sophisticated sound systems, not just a simple pc :)

Comment: I don't have an Ubuntu system to test with, but http://superuser.com/questions/87571/how-to-hear-mic-sound-over-speakers-ubuntu-karmic might have the solution.

Comment: Posting links to Google searches is actually a rather insulting manner of answering the question. It is like sarcastically asking if the user has searched on Google yet.